# Spring boot servlet shows performance problems in Tomcat but not Jetty

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jetty, saxon

I have a spring boot java servlet that is running great under Jetty but has a performance problem when running under Tomcat, which is our target deployment environment.

1. JAXB unmarshal is bottlenecked because the ServiceLoader is spending a lot of time looking up which TransformerFactory implementation to use.  ([YourKit profiling showing the look up for the TransformerFactory implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXGgq.png))
2. Saxon is the transform implementation and the jar is included in tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib and has the proper META-INF/services file
3. This issue is not present when using Jetty as the servlet container
4. I have confirmed running under both Jetty and Tomcat I get the correct implementation for a TransformerFactory from the correct jar
5. Explicitly adding the mapping to the Tomcat JAVA_OPTS options solves the problem:

   -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl

Edited:
Our xml fetch/transform time in Jetty is about 5s vs. 20s under Tomcat and it's directly due to the class loader searching for our TransformerFactory.

I am able to fix the problem by explicitly specifying the TransformerFactory in our servlet configuration but my question remains:
Why does Tomcat require this explicit setProperty and the Jetty container does not?

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");

    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
```

Sorry if this is a rudimentary question, I'm an old C++ dog learning Java and web apps/servlet tricks.

Comment: One question to 4: with "when running the executable .jar or .war file" you mean that those files use embedded jetty instead of embedded tomcat?

Comment: When I did that test they were using embedded Tomcat.  Jetty has always been external in all my tests.

Comment: I have also read the docs on class loader for both Jetty and Tomcat.  From those, I would not expect any difference because both containers have to obey class loader rules for servlet containers setup in the standard.

Comment: Too board, you need to find out "how" this factory is resolved, maybe annotation scanning? Why not set the Factory programmatically?

Comment: Edited to try to provide more data and narrow the question.  I have solved the problem, but it feels like a hack and that there might be a more proper way to fix it.  Also, I am extremely curious as to why Jetty works fine without the additional setting and only Tomcat requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JAXP system property identifying the factory is not set, then JAXP searches the classpath for a JAR file with information about transformer factories in the services file of the JAR file manifest. That search can be pretty expensive in the case where there are many JARs on the classpath, and it is definitely best avoided. The most likely explanation for the performance difference you are seeing is that your Tomcat configuration has a lot more JAR files to search than the Jetty configuration.

By far the fastest way to instantiate Saxon is to do it directly, and avoid the JAXP mechanisms entirely:

```
TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()
```

This is also more reliable; if your application is tested with Saxon and you don't trust it to run with any old XSLT 1.0 processor that's lying around on the classpath, then you might as well hard-code use of Saxon into the application source code. The only advantage of the JAXP mechanism if you want your application to be able to run with different JAXP XSLT implementations, with the choice made at run-time.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I think that supports my solution of hard coding the System.setProperty to define which implementation we're using.  Does the code snippet you provided actually set the TransformerFactory for the entire application?  I'm asking because we are not in directly control of when/where the TransformerFactory is created.  Basically I want to know if I should replace my System call with your code snippet in my configure method

Comment: No, the code supplied replaces anything that does `TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()`, and assumes you have access to the places in the application where that is done. If you can't change the code in this way, using the system property is your best alternative, but the downside is it applies to the whole application, and may change the XSLT engine used by parts of the application that have only been tested with the default JDK engine and break when a different one is used.